# Filter on extended property with unknown number of preceeding zeroes in Powershell Get-ADUser Query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to match users in my AD by EmployeeID. The trouble is that some users are listed with preceding zeroes, some are not. E.g. some users are 001234 where others are 01234 or 1234, so I cannot use the 'eq' comparison. Is there a reasonable query I can use to filter on this without any mismatches? I tried the below, which almost works.

```
$employeeID = "*$($user.EmployeeID)"
$ADUser = Get-ADuser -Filter "EmployeeID -like '$employeeID'" -Properties SAMAccountName, EmployeeID
```

Problem being, this will return things like 001234 and 012345, when searching for 1234. Other examples are 000123 and 002123, etc. will both turn up for the user with EID 123.

Is there a better way I can structure this? I have looked at the Get-ADUSer and about_ActiveDirectory_Filter technet documentation, but none of it quite covers what I want. I am not quite sure how to construct this to only search for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that all EmployeeID attributes are numeric, you could do

```
# convert the EmployeeID string to an integer number
$employeeID = [int]$user.EmployeeID
# Pre-Filter the results and refine in the Where-Object clause 
$ADUser = Get-ADuser -Filter "EmployeeID -like '*$employeeID'" -Properties EmployeeID | 
            Where-Object {[int]$_.EmployeeID -eq $employeeID}
```

<sup>`Get-ADUser` returns these properties by default: *DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName*, so SamAccountName does not need to be specified in the `-Properties` parameter</sup>

Comment: I actually went back to this today and decided to do it this way... the thought to do it this way came to me in the shower, but storing it as an int makes it much easier to work with later on down the line in my script. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reg = "[0]*1940$"
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmployeeID | select EmployeeID
$users | ? {$_.EmployeeID -match $reg}
```

I did some further testing and googling and ended up here - Search, then Regex the result. Yes this is slow but I am building $users then matching against the regex once per week, so not terribly concerned.